Minimal rank of a non-trivial matrix in a linear subspace $\mathcal{S} \subseteq \mathfrak{so}_n(\mathbb{R})$
Given $n$ and a linear subspace $\mathcal{S} \subseteq \mathfrak{so}_n(\mathbb{R})$ of skew-symmetric matrices, I would need an algorithm (i.e. something I can implement in a computer) to determine
\begin{equation}
\min \{ \, \mathrm{rank}(M) \, : \, M\in  \mathcal{S} \setminus \{0\} \, \}.
\end{equation}
Of course, every element $M$ of $\mathcal{S}$ can be written as linear combination $M = \sum_{i=1}^d a_i S_i$, where $\{\, S_i \,\}_{i=1}^d$ is a basis for $\mathcal{S}$.
A non-trivial matrix in $\mathcal{S}$ of rank less than $2k$ exists if and only if the system of polynomial equations
\begin{equation}
P_X(a_1,\dots,a_d) = 0, \quad X \subseteq \{1,\dots,n\}, \, |X|=2k
\end{equation}
has a non-trivial solution, where $P_X(a_1,\dots,a_d)$ is the polynomial I get by imposing that the principal minor of $M = \sum_{i=1}^d a_i S_i$, with rows and colums in $X$, has determinant zero.
By general theory of skew-symmetric matrices, these polynomials are squares of Pfaffian polynomials (precomposed with a linear change of variables). Is there an algorithm to determine if an arbitrary system of this kind of polynomials has a non-trivial solutions? Otherwise, is there another clever way to approach this problem?

The problem of finding the minimal rank in a linear or affine subspace of a matrix space is usually called a minrank problem. These problems are usually hard. We considered the homogeneous problem for arbitrary matrices (M. Bläser et al. "On the Orbit Closure Containment Problem and Slice Rank of Tensors", SODA 2021, pp. 2565–2584) and proved that checking whether minimal rank is 1 or not is NP-hard, and this can be easily extended to antisymmetric spaces and minrank 2 by considering block matrices of the form $\begin{bmatrix} 0 & A \\ -A^\top & 0\end{bmatrix}$.
In fact, every homogeneous system of (dense) polynomial equations can be encoded as the problem of checking if the minimal rank in your problem is $2$.
Here is the sketch of the construction:

Suppose we have a homogeneous system $\begin{cases} F_k(x_1, \dots, x_n) = 0\end{cases}$. Suppose $d$ is the maximal among the degrees of $F_k$. We can assume that all polynomials have degree $d$ by considering instead of one equation $F = 0$ with $\deg F = e < d$ several equations of the form $mF = 0$ where $m$ ranges over all monomials of degree $d - e$. The size of the polynomial system increases, but if the polynomial are presented by writing all their coefficients, then the size increase is only polynomial.
Now, instead of searching for indeterminates $x_i$, we can instead search for the values of all monomials $z_{i_1,\dots,i_n} = x_1^{i_1}\dots x_n^{i_n}$ with $i_1 + \dots + i_n = d$. The degree $d$ equations in $x$ become linear equations in $z$, and we add additional quadratic equations $z_{\mathbf{i}}z_{\mathbf{j}} = z_{\mathbf{k}}z_{\mathbf{l}}$ for $\mathbf{i} + \mathbf{j} = \mathbf{k} + \mathbf{l}$. Equivalently, instead of the projective variety $X$ defined by vanishing of polynomials $F_k$  we consider the degree $d$ Veronese embedding of $X$, which is now defined by linear and quadratic equations.
After that we use linear algebra to eliminate linear equations so that only quadratic equations in a subset of $z$ variables remain.
Finally, the existence of a nontrivial solution for a system of homogeneous quadratic equations $y^T Q_k y = 0$ is equivalent to the existence of a nonzero rank one matrix $y y^T$ in the orthogonal complement $\mathcal{S}$ of the matrix space spanned by all $Q_k^\dagger$, as $y^T Q y = \operatorname{tr}(y^\top Q y) = \operatorname{tr}(Q y y^\top) = \left<Q^\dagger, y y^\top\right>$, and this is equivalent to the existence of a rank $2$ antisymmetric matrix in the space $\{ \begin{bmatrix} 0 & A \\ -A^\top & 0\end{bmatrix} \mid A \in \mathcal{S} \}$


That is very nice! Thank you so much, this is exactly  the kind of theoretical answer I wanted. So, if I understood correctly, every instance of the decision problem of determining if the minimal rank in my problem is less that some $k$ can be reconducted to the problem you proved to be NP-hard. I just needed to know this was somehow computable but it ended up being more interesting. Thanks again.
